# How can I do to use Angular 5/6 for frontend and Codeigniter 3 for backend in the same web app?

Tags: php, javascript, web-framework, codeigniter, angular2

I have this project I want to do, using **Angular 5/6** for *frontend* and **Codeigniter 3** for *backend*. The problem is that I don't know how to combine the two, and all the tutorials I looked were using ***AngularJS*** which is *version 1* whereas i'm using *version 6*, and it didn't really work.

I am looking for something like [JavaScript & CSS Scaffolding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend) using **Angular 5/6** (and not *AngularJS*) with **Codeigniter 3**

Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 1):

You can start developing your application in angular 5. And backend can be anything . You just need an API call which can be done using httpClient in angular.
Please refer below link.
https://next.angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer ma'am but i wanted to know how can i host my angular application. i.e., after ng build i get the compiled js in dist folder but how to host it on server